# ExtJs- TreeStore AJAX Proxy not sending request to Server or TreeStore is not loading

Tags: extjs

Ext js TreeStore is not loading

```
Ext.ns('App');

Ext.onReady(function() {
  Ext.QuickTips.init();
  App.PPPExplorer.init(); 
});


App.PPPExplorer = {

// Initialize application
init : function(serverCfg) {        
    this.PPP = this.createPPP();
},

createPPP : function() {


// Set up a model to use in our Store
Ext.define('Summary', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
  fields: [
     {name: 'pid', type: 'string'}
  ]
});

var myStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
 model: 'Summary',
 storeId:'myStore',
 proxy: {
     type : 'ajax',
     method: 'GET',
     url: '/Explorer.do?method=getPPP&search=true',
     reader: {
         type: 'json'
     },
     root: {
         pid: 'src',
         text:'test',
         expanded: true
     },
 },
 autoLoad: true
 });

Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
    title: 'Simple Tree',
    width: 200,
    height: 150,
    store: myStore,
//      rootVisible: true,
    renderTo: 'Explorer',


        columns: [{
             xtype: 'treecolumn', //this is so we know which column will show the tree
             text: 'Reference',
             flex: 2,
             sortable: true,
             dataIndex: 'pid',
             locked: true
        }]
});


  }
}
```

I am using Ext js 4.2 Version

I have used treeStore, treePanel in the above code, somehow Proxy call is not sent to Server. There was no error message in the console

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Root definition** should be **inside TreeStore** definition as follows (it's on the proxy declaration now):

```
var myStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
model: 'Summary',
storeId: 'myStore',
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/Explorer.do?method=getPPP&search=true',
    reader: {
        type: 'json'
    }
},
autoLoad: true,
root: {
    pid: 'src',
    text: 'test',
    expanded: true
}
```

});

That way your code works, you can [**see it here**](http://jsfiddle.net/overlordhammer/DB6vY/)